# procfs1.c of "The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide"

Tags: linux, module, kernel

I was playing around the example in Chapter 5.1 of ["The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide"](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x710.html). I compiled the source code, loaded the module, and then when I did a `cat /proc/helloworld`, I noticed the following in `/var/log/messages`: (I modified the original source code to print the values of `ret` and `offset`)

`Oct 31 23:46:00 vm-ubuntu1010 kernel: [221941.287939] procfile_read (/proc/helloworld) called, ret=12, offset=0`

`Oct 31 23:46:00 vm-ubuntu1010 kernel: [221941.287955] procfile_read (/proc/helloworld) called, ret=0, offset=12`

`Oct 31 23:46:00 vm-ubuntu1010 kernel: [221941.287987] procfile_read (/proc/helloworld) called, ret=0, offset=12`

Based on the log message, the callback function `procfile_read` was called 3 times. What I don't understand is why it is 3 times instead of 2 times. The first time `procfile_read` is called, it returns `12`, so the callback function will be called a 2nd time, during which `0` is returned. But why a 3rd time is called? I thought a return value of `0` (of the 2nd call) indicates that the system call `read` (and thus `procfile_read`) will not be called again.

Please help me understand this problem. Thanks a lot!